# Account for system zoom on images in HTML

Tags: html, css

In a minimal HTML page with `<img src="example.png">`, I only see the original quality if I zoom to 80% - reproduced in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge. Using `srcset="example.png 1.25x"` fixes this.

This appears to be due to changing my system display setting (Windows 10):

[image]

yet, other sites work fine. I've read that one way's to provide multi-resolution images via `srcset`, but suppose that's not an option. (I tried providing the *same* image at  `1.25x`, which worked for *me*, but broke it for a user with 100% system zoom.)

How else can I address this? It's just about resizing the image appropriately, but don't know how to do this portably with HTML/CSS.

---

#### MRE: Code + image

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="example.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

^ this is blurry for me unless I zoom to 1/1.25 = 0.8.

Comment: This cannot be overcome, because the HTTP client (f.e. Firefox) itself is relative to the (operating) system (f.e. Windows). And HTML was never intended to be pixel perfect (although CSS implies this with its unit `px`). If form is more important to you than function, you cannot expect an allrounder like a web browser to fit your needs. Compile a program which is able to detect such a system setting and act upon it.

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks, yes my question includes such a program as a resolution. But I'm guessing it'll have to be made from scratch.